# NodeJS: XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am trying to use ajax with my express app, but the success function does not get called. Don't know if there is something wrong with my code or if it is the Express framework.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000. Cross origin requests are
>   only supported for HTTP

is what I get in my console. I have tried to change the url to `"http://localhost:3000/"` but then I get a 404.

Here is my code:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "localhost:3000",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function() {
            console.log('test');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have an `app.post('/')` action? `app.get('/')` won't respond to a `POST` request.

Comment: Ajax requests aren't typically supported by `file://`, if that's what you're using (*Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP*). You'll want to setup or create a 2nd `http://` server to request the page from for testing cross-origin Ajax.